# How to clean a sync.map?

Tags: go

I can't have access to map inside Range loop method. I just want an equivalente method of normal map apply in sync.map 
https://play.golang.org/p/515_MFqSvCm

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
)

type list struct {
    code string
    fruit
}

type fruit struct {
    name     string
    quantity int
}

func main() {
    lists := []list{list{"asd", fruit{"Apple", 5}}, list{"ajsnd", fruit{"Apple", 10}}, list{"ajsdbh", fruit{"Peach", 15}}}
    map1 := make(map[string]fruit)
    var map2 sync.Map
    for _, e := range lists {
        map1[e.code] = e.fruit
        map2.Store(e.code, e.fruit)
    }

    //erase map
    for k, _ := range map1 {
        delete(map1, k)
    }

    //can´t pass map as argument,so I can´t delete it´s values
    map2.Range(aux)
}

func aux(key interface{}, value interface{}) bool {
    map2.Delete(key) //doesn´t work
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For example,

```
//erase map
map2.Range(func(key interface{}, value interface{}) bool {
    map2.Delete(key)
    return true
})
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/PTASV3sEIxJ

**Or**

```
//erase map
delete2 := func(key interface{}, value interface{}) bool {
    map2.Delete(key)
    return true
}
map2.Range(delete2)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/jd8dl71ee94

**Or**

```
func eraseSyncMap(m *sync.Map) {
    m.Range(func(key interface{}, value interface{}) bool {
        m.Delete(key)
        return true
    })
}

func main() {
    // . . .

    //erase map
    eraseSyncMap(&map2)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/lCBkUv6GJIO

**Or**

```
//erase map: A zero sync.Map is empty and ready for use.
map2 = sync.Map{}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/s-KYelDxqFB

Comment: actually i think the last one might be dangerous when there is a race condition on `map2` object

Comment: The last one would most certainly ignore any semaphore internal to the `sync.Map` structure - request somebody to concur on this please

Comment: Manipulation of data inside a `sync.Map` should only occur via the provided functions. The last one does not do so and is therefore dangerous.